# Can we add dynamic Header and Footer using HttpModule in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, header, httpmodule, footer

I looked at the example at [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/headerfooter.aspx). Its ASP .NET example. Can we have same functionality in MVC project?
OR Can we add ".ascx" output just after first `<form>` tag and just before last `</form>` tag using HttpModule in MVC? Basically i want to add some dynamic content in each response but couldn't figure out.

Thanks for any help...!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use ASP.NET master pages?

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp

Comment: Andy, Thanks for considering this question.

Actually I am working on Web Portal. I have 3-4 WebSites developed in MVC and 3-4 WebSites developed in Java. I want to add common header and footer in all websites. We are using Reverse Proxy to forward request to specific website. 
In my understanfing, When i receive response If i could add dynamic content (.ascx file) to Response would be enough. Dynamic content would have Menu,Login Information, etc.

I can't use MasterPage because we have Java too. 

Any other idea would be appreciated.